# Python code not running except print function?

Tags: 20.04, python

I have just moved from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I use VS Code as a text editor (installed extensions such as python and code-runner). I have multiple python versions (i use Python 3.9.2).As i code in python i wrote a simple while loop code .

```
i = 0
while i>10:
   print("yess")
```

[The code gave no output. Image Below .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHz3M.png)

But if i run any print function or if else program it gives the output.

[Image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS71v.png)

Please someone help regarding this ....

Comment: This is a python question not ubuntu..

Comment: Hey, you might wanna checkout stackoverflow! They may be better suited to help.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not the right place to post programming questions..
Your code should be as follows:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
   print("yess")
   i += 1
```

Like that, you'll get **yess** printed 10 times.

Comment: Thnks dude . i did that worked that was a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you run your code via extensions it fails.
A better way is always to run your code in terminal either using a virtual environment or in built Python environment.

For instance,suppose the file containing the above call is yes.py run it like this python3 yes.py